# How to create a Java 8 Stream from an iterator?

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it possible to create a Stream from an Iterator, in which the sequence of objects is the same as that generated by calling the iterator's next() method repeatedly? The specific case I am thinking of concerns the use of the iterator returned by TreeSet.descendingIterator(), but I can imagine other circumstances in which an iterator, but not the collection it references, is available.

For example, for a `TreeSet<T> tset` we can write `tset.stream()...` and get a stream of the objects in that set, in the set's sort order, but what if we want them in a different order, such as that available through using `descendingIterator()`? I am imagining something like `tset.descendingIterator().stream()...` or `stream( tset.descendingIterator() )...`, though neither of these forms are valid.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Java 8, which is why I'm commenting instead of answering, but are you looking for Java's [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) interface? It sounds like it might fit your needs (for some operations, at least... Doesn't sound like it'd work if you needed it to function in a more iterator-like manner)

Comment: @user3580294 The term stream is unfortunately overloaded, but I am referring to the java.util.stream.Stream<T> interface. I will add an example.

Comment: So you wanted to create a `java.util.stream.Stream<T>` from a `java.util.Iterator<T>`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For the particular example of `NavigableSet.descendingIterator()`, I think the simplest way is to use [`NavigableSet.descendingSet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#descendingSet--) instead.

But given you are probably interested in the more general case, the following seems to work:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class Streams {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
        set.add("C");
        set.add("A");
        set.add("B");

        Iterator<String> iterator = set.descendingIterator();

        int characteristics = Spliterator.DISTINCT | Spliterator.SORTED | Spliterator.ORDERED;
        Spliterator<String> spliterator = Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, characteristics);

        boolean parallel = false;
        Stream<String> stream = StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, parallel);

        stream.forEach(System.out::println); // prints C, then B, then A
    }
}
```

In short, you have to create a [`Spliterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) from the `Iterator` first using one of the static methods in [`Spliterators`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.html). Then you can create a `Stream` using the static methods in [`StreamSupport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html).

I don't have that much experience with creating Spliterators and Streams by hand yet, so I can't really comment on what the characteristics should be or what effect they will have. In this particular simple example, it didn't seem to matter whether I defined the characteristics as above, or whether I set it to 0 (i.e. no characteristics). There is also a method in `Spliterators` for creating a Spliterator with an initial size estimate - I suppose in this particular example you could use `set.size()`, but if you want to handle arbitrary Iterators I guess this won't be the case. Again, I'm not quite sure what effect it has on performance.

Comment: Thanks for both the general solution and for bringing NavigableSet to my attention. From the StreamSupport documentation, I see that java.util.function.Supplier<T> provides an interface for feeding data into streams.

Comment: See Karols answer below, which should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 54):

```
static <T> Stream<T> iteratorToFiniteStream(final Iterator<T> iterator) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false);
}

static <T> Stream<T> iteratorToInfiniteStream(final Iterator<T> iterator) {
    return Stream.generate(iterator::next);
}
```

Comment: I agree, and I know it works, but I don't understand [why the lambda can be assigned to the Iterable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841310/explain-how-this-supplier-lambda-can-be-assigned-to-an-iterable)

Comment: The second solution will lead to an exception in many (most?) use cases. For example: `Iterator<Integer> iterator = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3).iterator(); Stream.generate(iterator::next).forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));` prints 0, 1, 2, 3 and then throws a `NoSuchElementException`. The problem is that `iterator.hasNext()` is never called.

Comment: @JonaChristopherSahnwaldt Cause your 4 elements stream is far away from "Infinity" ;) Don't you think that in second method there is no need to check if iterator "hasNext"?

Comment: @KarolKról No, I don't think so. In many cases, the second method will lead to an exception. The first method is much better, and it also works for "infinite" Iterators (which are very rare, in my experience).

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't create a stream, but `Iterator` also has a method called `forEachRemaining`:

```
someIterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
someIterator.forEachRemaining(s -> s.doSomething());
//etc.
```

The argument you pass in is a [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) which is the same thing you pass to [Stream::forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-).

[Here are the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-) for that method.
note that **you can't continue the "chain"** like you can with a stream. But I've still found this helpful the few times I've wanted a Stream from an Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

As it was written by [Karol Król](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29010716/11733759) for infinite stream you can use this:

```java
Stream.generate(iterator::next)
```

but you can also use it for finite stream with [`takeWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) since Java 9

```
Stream.generate(iterator::next).takeWhile((v) -> iterator.hasNext())
```

Comment: This skips the last element the iterator returns.

Comment: I verified @MichaelB's comment and don't see an easy fix: `Iterator iter = List.of(1, 2, 3).iterator();
Stream.generate(iter::next).takeWhile((v) -> iter.hasNext()).forEach(System.out::println);` gives 1 and 2.