# Java 8 stream from a JPA Repository

Tags: parallel-processing, java-8, spring-data-jpa, java-stream, spliterator

I would like to create a Stream from a JPA Repository. The goal is to map the Entities coming from the Repo (which could be more than a million) to other Entities which will in turn be stored in another Repo.

So far I built a Collector which will collect a given number (e.g. 1000) Entities and then store them into the target Repo. This will work in a parallel Stream. What I need now is a good way to fetch Entities from the source Repo and feed them into the Stream as they are needed.

Most promising so far was to implement a Supplier (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) to build the Stream via generate but I did not find a way to terminate the process when the query to the source Repo does not provide another Entity.

Any pointers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Java 8 Stream from an iterator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439780/how-to-create-a-java-8-stream-from-an-iterator)

Comment: Suppliers are only for infinite streams. You can write a plain old iterator.

Comment: Spliterator was my second guess. I was hoping for a more straight forward solution. Problem still is that I do not want to fetch the complete collection of Entities and simply using the Repository as Iterator will do no good.

Comment: You can load the entities in batches.

Comment: I know that I can do pagination. What I want is to fetch the Entities from the Source Repository as needed, and feed them in the parallel Stream where they are mapped, accumulated and stored into a target repository.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something or there's a misunderstaning, but I don't understand why pagination doesn't meet your requirements. Loading 20 entities at once or one after another doesn't make much difference. The former would be even more efficient, imho, and **does** meet the requirement _"as needed"_.

Comment: Maybe I should be more pragmatic about this. I was hoping for a sleek solution that would integrate more seamless with the whole stream idea. Repeatedly dropping in Chunks of Entities somehow does not nicely integrate with the Stream concept. But I guess I will have to make do with it :-(

Comment: Why do you think that it does not integrate nicely with stream concept? Whether the iterator reads one entity after another, batches of 20 or all at once doesn't make a difference to the stream or for your stream related code. For what it's worth: You could also load all the ids at first and then read one entity after another.

Answer (score 3):

We recently added support for this in Spring Data JPA (and MongoDB) in our latest RC1 Release of the Spring Data Fowler Release Train.

[Example for Stream returned by a delegating default method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/pull/61)
[Example for "real streaming" Stream](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/pull/63)

Comment: Hi Thomas, big thanks for that. I actually blogged about how meeting you in person got this going (in german): http://blog.flavia-it.de/trefft-euch/

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to express the source as `Supplier` implementation you may also be able to implement a `Spliterator`. Instead of `Supplier.get` you would implement `boolean tryAdvance(Consumer)` which will not return the new value but invoke `accept` on the `Consumer`, if there is a new item or return `false` otherwise. For most cases this simplifies the implementation compared to an `Iterator` where you have to deal with the two methods `hasNext` and `next` which could be invoked in arbitrary order.

You have to implement a few more methods for `Spliterator` but thankfully there are straight-forward ways for implementating them.

```
public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
    return null;// simple answer when splitting is not supported
}
public long estimateSize() {
    return Long.MAX_VALUE; // the value which should be used for UNKNOWN
}
public int characteristics() {
    return 0; // no flags but check out whether some flags fit
}
```

For the `characteristics` method it’s worth looking for [the possible values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#characteristics--) as they might improve the stream processing if they fit to your source characteristics.

Once you have your `Spliterator` you can create a stream out of it:

```
Stream<T> s=StreamSupport.stream(sp, false);
```

If your source fits more into the `hasNext`/`next` pattern, you may implement an ordinary `Iterator` and let the JRE create a `Spliterator` like described in [“How to create a Java 8 Stream from an iterator?”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23439780/2711488)

Answer (score 0):

A simple example might be:

```
  @Repository
  public class MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {           
  }

  @Component
  public class MyEntityService {

       @Autowired
       private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;


       public void() {
            // if the findAll() method returns List
            Stream<MyEntity> streamFromList = myEntityRepository.findAll().stream();


            // if the findAll() method returns Iterable
            Stream<MyEntity> streamFromIterable = StreamSupport.stream(myEntityRepository.findAll().spliterator(), true);

       }
  }
```

Comment: As far as I know findAll will fetch the complete Collection eagerly. I need lazy fetching.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for all the contributions. I combined what was said and implemented what I need. Maybe the implementation will clarify what I wanted to start with.

I created two classes, *RepositryCollector* and *RepositorySpliterator*.

```
public class RepositoryCollector<T> implements Collector<T, Tuple2<Integer,List<T>>, Integer>{

    private JpaRepository<T, ?> repository;
    private int threshold;

    public BinaryOperator<Tuple2<Integer, List<T>>> combiner() {
        return (listTuple, itemsTuple) -> {
            List<T> list = listTuple._2;
            List<T> items = itemsTuple._2;
            list.addAll(items);
            int sum = listTuple._1 + itemsTuple._1;
            if(list.size() >= this.threshold){
                this.repository.save(list);
                this.repository.flush();
                list = new LinkedList<>();
            }
            return new Tuple2<>(sum, list);
        };
    }
}
```

I omit the other function which are required for a Collector since all relevant information is present in the combiner. Same holds for the Spliterator.

```
public class RepositorySpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {

    private Slice<T> slice;
    private Function<Pageable, Slice<T>> getSlice;
    private Iterator<T> sliceIterator;

    public RepositorySpliterator(Pageable pageable, Function<Pageable, Slice<T>> getSlice) {
        this.getSlice = getSlice;
        this.slice = this.getSlice.apply(pageable);
        this.sliceIterator = slice.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        if(sliceIterator.hasNext()) {
            action.accept(sliceIterator.next());
            return true;
        } else if (slice.hasNext()) {
            this.slice = getSlice.apply(slice.nextPageable());
            this.sliceIterator = this.slice.iterator();
            if(sliceIterator.hasNext()){
                action.accept(sliceIterator.next());
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Stream<T> getStream(boolean parallel){
        return StreamSupport.stream(this, parallel);
    }
}
```

As you can see I put in a helper function to generate the Stream I need. Maybe this is a tad sloppy but... meh.

So now I just need a few lines of code in my mapping classes to get things going.

```
    public void start(Timestamp startTimestamp, Timestamp endTimestamp) {
        new RepositorySpliterator<>(
                new PageRequest(0, 10000), pageable -> sourceRepository.findAllBetween(startTimestamp, endTimestamp, pageable))
                .getStream(true)
                .map(entity -> mapToTarget(endTimestamp, entity))
                .collect(new RepositoryCollector<>(targetRepository, 1000));
    }
```

The mapper will fetch 10000 Entities from the source, will pour them into the stream pool so they can be mapped and stored. Whenever *one* of the streams runs out of new Entities, a fresh batch will be fetched and fed into the same stream pool.

If there are glaring errors in my implementation feel free to comment and improve!