# how converte large XML file to stream-like-java8 of object

Tags: java, xml, stream, java-8

Hy,
I have a (very)large XML file (100GB) with a list of foo, I want to convert-it into a stream like they where introduce into java 8  of object:

Any idea of lib or code sample?

at the beginning:

```
<foos> 
  <foo>...</foo>
  <foo>...</foo>
</foos>
```

at the end:

```
Stream<Foo>  foosStream = ????("foo.xml")
streamFoos.forEach(foo->foo.doFooStuffs());
```

Edit:
@Pierre Thank-you, here is the implementation of your solution:

```
  try {
            XMLEventReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().
                    createXMLEventReader(stream);
            final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(XXXXX.class).createUnmarshaller();

            Iterator<XXXXX> it = new XmlIterator<>(reader, unmarshaller, "xxxxxx");
            return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(it, Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
        } catch (XMLStreamException e1) {
            logger.error("XMLStreamException", e1);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            logger.error("JAXBException", e);
        }
```

and

```
public class XmlIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    XMLEventReader reader;

    XMLEvent event;

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
    String name;

    public XmlIterator(XMLEventReader reader, Unmarshaller unmarshaller, String name) {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.unmarshaller = unmarshaller;
        this.name = name;
        try {
            reader.next();
            this.event = reader.peek();
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            logger.error("", e);
            event = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        try {
            while (event != null && !(event.isStartElement() && name.equals(event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart()))) {
                Object a = reader.next();
                event = reader.peek();
            }
            return event != null;

        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            logger.error("", e);
            event = null;
        }
        return event != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        try {
            T next = ((JAXBElement<T>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader)).getValue();
            event = reader.peek();
            return next;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            logger.error("error during unmarshalling ", e);
            return null;
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            logger.error("error during stream ", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the different techniques and APIs to read an XML file in Java? Which one would you think is suited here? How large the XML files are going to be? Probably, you want to take a look at [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/api.html) but could you add more context into your question?

Comment: Yes, I know a lot of lib, but they are all very low-level.  I don't understand why in 2016 I still have to analyse manualy the start_element to generate myself the stream, when I could juste have to specify the Xpath.

Comment: " I still have to analyse manualy the start_element to generate myself the stream"  : have a look at jaxb ( = define a xml schema for your data )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Create a Stax Event reader https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/example.html reading your xml file
- Each time you see a tag 'foo' (using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html#peek() ) , use the Stax reader to parse and build your object `Foo`

  ```
  Foo readFoo(XMLEventReader xmlIn) throws XMLStreamException {
     (...)
     return foo; 
  }
  ```
- implements a java.util.Iterator that will use the previous function to return the 'next()' Foo
- convert this iterator to a stream [How to create a Java 8 Stream from an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439780)

Comment: Probably easier to just not use a stream and call the consumer method yourself for every `Foo` encountered call...

Comment: all the lib than i find seem dated of before the stream, there is no more recent lib?

Comment: Does this require the whole XML to be in memory before parsing starts?

Comment: After reading on Stax, I can see this is do-able. How did I not know about this? This is great