# Iterating through json elements using java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to iterate through the elements in a JsonNode and check if they match some condition. I want to use Streams instead of using the classic iterator. I have code similar to this:

```
return Stream.generate(jsonNode.fields()::next)
            .allMatch(entry -> {
              switch (entry.getKey()) {
                case "a":
                  return evaluateA(entry.getValue());
                case "b":
                  return evaluateB(entry.getValue());
                default:
                  return false;
              }
            });
```

But when I run this, I get a java.util.NoSuchElementException. I'm guessing the return statements within the switch case are causing this error. If that is the case, how do I handle this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your `switch`. `Stream.generate(jsonNode.fields()::next)` creates an *infinite* stream. There is no check for `hasNext` in your code. Maybe you’re looking for [How to create a Java 8 Stream from an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23439780/2711488)

Comment: `Stream.generate` generates an infinite stream. Surely you don't have an infinite number of fields in your JSON node :)

Comment: You could probably use `takeWhile` and `hasNext` to limit the stream.

Comment: I suggest that you change your title to something about using iterators with streams, which would make the question a lot more useful.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question and mark as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gson-utils](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/gson-utils):

```java
Reader in = null;
Iterator<Book> it = GsonUtils.readListLazy(in, Book.class);
```